# How to ask Retrofit2, to don't encode my dynamic URL?

Tags: android, amazon-s3, retrofit2

I'm trying to upgrade my code base from Retrofit 1.9 to version 2.0.
I have no problem in upload of an image in version 1.9. However I'm getting following S3 response error after I changed it to version 2.0.

This is my interface to upload image in Retrofit v1.9:

```
public interface IFileUploadAPI
{
    @PUT("/{url}")
    void uploadFile(@Path(value = "url", encode = false) String url, @Body() TypedFile file,
                    Callback<UploadFileResponse> callback);
}
```

I've changed it to following code on Retrofit v2.0:

```
public interface IFileUploadAPI
{
    @PUT
    Call<UploadFileResponse> uploadFile(@Url String url, @Body RequestBody file);
}
```

And I'm implementing it in this way.

```
public class MyFileUploadAPI
{
    private IFileUploadAPI mService;

    public MyFileUploadAPI()
    {
        final Retrofit adapter = new Retrofit.Builder() //
                        .baseUrl(MyAPIConstant.API_URL_BASE) // This URL will be ignored as we are using dynamic url. So no matters what it is.
                        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(GsonUtils.getGson())) //
                        .client(ASDKApplication.getInstance().getOkHttpClient()) //
                        .build();

        this.mService = adapter.create(IFileUploadAPI.class);
    }

    public void uploadFile(final String url, final String filePath, final String mimeType)
    {
        RequestBody file = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse(mimeType), filePath);
        Call<UploadFileResponse> call = mService.uploadFile(url, file);
                call.enqueue(new Callback<HitchUploadFileResponse>()
        {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<UploadFileResponse> call, Response<UploadFileResponse> response)
            {
                UploadFileResponse uploadFileResponse = new UploadFileResponse();

                if (response.isSuccessful() && response.body() != null)
                {
                    uploadFileResponse = response.body();
                }

                // Rest of code...
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<UploadFileResponse> call, Throwable t)
            {
                Logger.error(TAG, "uploadFile.onFailure(), msg: " + t.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So, when user click on `Upload` button, I call an API and it returns me a url that I have to call. The response looks likes:

```
[{"uploadSignedURL":"https://my-account.s3.amazonaws.com/license/1000_front_1464988248.jpeg?AWSAccessKeyId=MY_ID\u0026Expires=1464991848\u0026Signature=NhStdEX8RH3J0uzvVa6h%2FvN6FZQ%3D","filePath":"license/1000_front_1464988248.jpeg","target":"driving_license_front_img"}]
```

And finally the response to call of above url (http status code 403 forbidden):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error><Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code><Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.</Message><AWSAccessKeyId>MY_ID</AWSAccessKeyId><StringToSign>PUT

image/jpeg; charset=utf-8
1464991848
/my-account/license/1000_front_1464988248.jpeg</StringToSign><SignatureProvided>NhStdEX8RH3J0uzvVa6h/vN6FZQ=</SignatureProvided><StringToSignBytes>50 55 54 0a 0a 69 6d 61 67 65 2f 6a 70 65 67 3b 20 63 68 61 72 73 65 74 3d 75 74 66 2d 38 0b 31 34 36 34 39 39 31 38 34 38 0a 2f 6d 79 74 65 6b 73 69 3a 67 72 61 62 68 69 45 63 68 2f 6c 69 63 65 6e 73 65 2f 31 30 30 30 5f 66 72 6f 6e 74 5f 31 34 36 34 39 38 38 32 34 38 2e 6a 70 65 67</StringToSignBytes><RequestId>2D6D08FE4E34FCE5</RequestId><HostId>tpvmJdeRxtAzPxOk2zFwMF2Ne6hmNMkcaM9D7m/I13iynYGJyqtC0U72B2t41SDYfPBjCRTVyOY=</HostId></Error>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found what's wrong.

`okhttp` is adding `charset=utf-8` into my `contentType`.  Therefore my `contentType` becomes like this `contentType: image/jpeg; charset=utf-8`. I tested on Postman and by delete of `; charset=utf-8` I'm able to upload my image.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/25560731/513413 says the reason of adding `charset`. It's because I'm passing path to my image file. You can easily change

`RequestBody file = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse(mimeType), filePath);`

to

`RequestBody file = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse(mimeType), new File(filePath));`

There is one more important thing. Once you upload your image to S3, Amazon returns HTTP status code 200 with empty body. So you have to change the interface too.

```
public interface IFileUploadAPI
{
    @PUT
    Call<Void> uploadFile(@Url String url, @Body RequestBody file);
}
```